# React Multi Column Radio

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm implementing a worker shift scheduler in React. See screenshot below

[image]

I receive the following employee object from the backend:

```
[{
    "employeeId": "id",
    "name": "bob"
},{
    "employeeId": "id",
    "name": "steve",
}]
```

I also receive the following shifts object from the backend:

```
"shifts": [
  {
    "shiftStart": "03:00",
    "shiftEnd": "07:00"
  },
  {
    "shiftStart": "16:00",
    "shiftEnd": "24:00"
  },
  {
    "shiftStart": "18:00",
    "shiftEnd": "00:00"
  },
  {
    "shiftStart": "12:10",
    "shiftEnd": "17:10"
  }
]
```

I'm using [Radio component from ant-design](https://ant.design/components/radio/). My code is the following:

```
class PlanningShiftManagement extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            employees: [],
            shifts: [],
            employeeshifts: []
        }
        this._populateTableData = this._populateTableData.bind(this)
        this._handleChange = this._handleChange.bind(this)
    }

  _populateTableData(){
      return this.state.employees.map((employee,index) => {
          let employeecheckbox = this.state.shifts.map((shift) => {
              return(
                <RadioButton value={[`${shift.shiftStart}`, `${shift.shiftEnd}`, `${employee.key}`]} key={`${employee.title}-${shift.shiftStart}-${shift.shiftEnd}`}>{shift.shiftStart} - {shift.shiftEnd}</RadioButton>
              )
          });
          return(
              <tr key={employee.title}>
                  <td>{employee.title}</td>
                  <td>
                      <RadioGroup onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e.target.value)}>
                        {employeecheckbox}
                      </RadioGroup>
                    </td>
              </tr>
          )
      })
  }

  _handleChange() {

  }


    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Employee Name</th>
                            <th>Shifts</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this._populateTableData()}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Now, I'm struggli with how to work on the _handleChange() so that I can store the object in the employeeshifts state so I can send back to the backend.

```
[{
    "shiftStart": "20170313 10:00",
    "shiftEnd": "20170313 17:00",
    "employeeId": "id"
},
{
    "shiftStart": "20170313 10:00",
    "shiftEnd": "20170313 17:00",
    "employeeId": "id"
}]
```

Since each employee can only be assigned to one shift, it's a Radio element, so using .push() is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `employeeId` to `handleChange`:

```
  <RadioGroup onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e.target.value, employee.id)}>
```

Shape your `employeeshifts` as a object:

```
{
  "employeeId": {
    "shiftStart": "20170313 10:00",
    "shiftEnd": "20170313 17:00",
  },
}
```

And transform `employeeshifts` to array before send to server.